# Show multiple locations with a marker on google map when the user types the location on the textbox in the android application

Tags: java, android

This is the code I have added to show locations on the map. But from this only one point will be shown. I need to add multiple points. Please help me on this for my assignment.

```
 View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {

     switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.launchmap:                
     final EditText addressfield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);                   
     String addressInput = addressfield.getText().toString(); // Get  input text
     Intent geoIntent = new Intent (android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse ("geo:0,0?q=" +     addressInput)); // Prepare intent
     startActivity(geoIntent);  // Initiate lookupaddressInput
```

Comment: I've given you a down-vote because I see no evidence of effort on your part. We are not here to write your code for you!

Answer (score 1):

You are starting Google Maps or a similar maps applications with an Intent.

The available Intent are documented for example [here](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/62) and in the official [Android Documentations](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html). Sadly there is no documented way to show more then one location on the map.

If you want to show a map with multiple markers you may need to include the [Google Maps Framework](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) directly into your application